# warning occuring in php word occurence

Tags: php

I have written the following code to count the number of string occurrences in a given file.

**PHP**

```
<?php
$p = fopen("g.txt", "r");
$q = fread($p, filesize("g.txt"));
$t = explode(" ", $q);
$m = explode(" ", $q);
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
$r = 0;
$count = 0;
$c = count($t);
$d = array();
echo "count of".
"<br/>";
for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
  for ($j = $i; $j < $c; $j++) {
    if ($t[$i] == $t[$j]) {
      $count = $count + 1;
    }
  }
  for ($r = $i + 1; $r < $c; $r++) {
    if ($t[$i] == $t[$r])
      unset($t[$r]);
  }
  echo $t[$i].
  "=".$count.
  "<br/>";
  $count = 0;
}
?>
```

I am getting a notice of undefined offset on line numbers 17 and 24, though my output is coming out to be correct. Can you please help me in rectifying the above problem?

Comment: Please make that code more readable (clear variable names, indentation)! And mark lines 17 and 24 and attach the warnings!

Comment: What are the exact warnings?  What are the lines to which they refer?  And why can't you use consistent spacing and meaningful variable names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are deleting items from the array `$t`. You saved the count in `$c`, but the actual count will change by your last inner loop.

Even if you replace `$c` by `count($t)` everywhere, it will go wrong, because the last loop should be in reverse order, otherwise you skip items. For instance if you have the list 'a', 'b', 'c'. then when you delete 'b' and increment `$r`, you will not check 'c' at all.

So, if I fix those things, your code becomes as below. Although I didn't really check it for other issues. Frankly, I don't really get what is should do. ;-)

```
<?php
      $p=fopen("g.txt","r");
      $q=fread($p,filesize("g.txt"));
      $t=explode(" ",$q); 
      $m=explode(" ",$q);
      $i=0;
      $j=0;
      $r=0;
      $count=0;
      $d=array();
      echo "count of"."<br/>";
      for($i=0; $i<count($t); $i++)
        {
         for($j=$i; $j<count($t); $j++)
            {
             if($t[$i]==$t[$j])
                    {
                     $count=$count+1;
                    }
            }
        for($r=count($t) - 1; $r > $i; $r--)
           {
            if($t[$i]==$t[$r])
                unset($t[$r]);
           }
     echo $t[$i]."=".$count."<br/>";
     $count=0;
     }
     ?>
```

In conclusion, you should do more tests. If the outcome of this script was okay, then it was by accident.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. i didnt understand one thing that why if we have the list 'a', 'b', 'c'. then when we delete 'b' and increment $r, we will not check 'c' at all?